# How do I print the next item in a list that starts with a certain letter/symbol?

Tags: python, list

So I am making this troubleshooting system related to phones in Python that needs to give a solution after looking at the user's query. In my list, the keywords that will be matched to the user's query are first put in and then the relevant solution to those keywords. The problem is that different issues that the user might have have different number of keywords to choose from and if all of the solutions in my list start with a symbol such as **{** how can I write a code that prints the next item in the list starting with **{** ?

```
storage = ["wet", "water", "toilet", "{Wipe the phone and place it in a bag of rice for 24 hours.}"]
```

This is an example of the list that I made. The user's query is: "I dropped my phone in the toilet."

The solution to this problem is right after the word 'toilet' starting with a curly bracket. Can you please provide me with a code that will make the program print the next value in the list that starts with a curly bracket?

Comment: A list seems to be a bad choice of a data structure for this. Why don't you use a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do exactly what you asked: "Can you please provide me with a code that will make the program print the next value in the list that starts with a curly bracket?"

```
def findNextCurly(keyword):
  index = storage.index(keyword) + 1
  while not storage[index].startswith("{"):
    index = index+1
  print (storage[index][1:-1])

>>> findNextCurly('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in findNextCurly
ValueError: 'test' is not in list
>>> findNextCurly('wet')
Wipe the phone and place it in a bag of rice for 24 hours.
```

... but nothing more.

The notation `string[1:-1]` is called *string slicing* and is explained in [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). Here it is used to remove the first and last characters from the string – the curly brackets.

Comment: The program works but I don't understand what the code means :(

Comment: @ShrimatKapoor: that is quite surprising, considered I barely know Python at all. I suggest working on your Python skills.

Comment: I am a beginner and I will try to improve my skills. Can you tell me how I can print my answer without the curly brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Given a starting point like:

```
query = "I dropped my phone in the toilet."

storage = ["wet", "water", "toilet", "{Wipe the phone and place it in a bag of rice for 24 hours.}"]
```

First we would need some kind of flag that indicates when we have found a matching keyword, lets say:

```
found_word = False
```

then we just iterate over `storage` like so:

```
for word in storage:
```

however not all the entries in storage are keywords, some are special values that need to be treated differently:

```
for word in storage:
    if word.startswith("{"):
```

When we encounter a value like this, if we have found a keyword we want to print out this special value then stop looping:

```
    if word.startswith("{"):
        if found_word:
            print(word)
            break
```

otherwise if the keyword is in the query then we just set the flag to True:

```
    elif word in query:
        found_word = True
```

so our final code would be:

```
found_word = False

for word in storage:
    if word.startswith("{"):
        if found_word:
            print(word)
            break
    elif word in query:
        found_word = True
```

on the other hand, if you used a `dict` to store your data like:

```
wet_solve = "Wipe the phone and place it in a bag of rice for 24 hours."

solutions = {"wet":wet_solve, "water":wet_solve, "toilet":wet_solve}
```

Then you would just need to check all the words in the query for one in the solutions:

```
for word in query.split():
    if word in solutions:
        print(solutions[word])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by Rad Lexus will return any value that has a curly brace in it, i.e. it would also print `hello{brace`. If you only want the ones that start with a letter, try:

```
storage = ["wet", "water", "toilet", "{Wipe the phone and place it in a bag of rice for 24 hours.}"]

for s in storage:
    if s.startswith("{"):
        print(s)
```

Comment: You are correct, I missed that minor point. I just edited it into my own answer. Mind that your code prints *any* first item in `storage`, not the first one after a found keyword. From OP's wording it can be assumed `storage` will hold more items such as these.